# How to control Spark logging in IntelliJ

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea, log4j

I'm usually running stuff from JUnit but I've also tried running from `main` and it makes no difference.

I have read nearly two dozen SO questions, blog posts, and articles and tried almost everything to get Spark to stop logging so much.

Things I've tried:

`log4j.properties` in resources folder (in `src` and `test`)

Using `spark-submit` to add a `log4j.properties` which failed with "`error: missing application resources`"

`Logger.getLogger("com").setLevel(Level.WARN);`

`Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN);`

`Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN);`

`Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN);`

`spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("WARN");`

In another project I got the logging to be quiet with:

```
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN);
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

but it is not working here.

How I'm creating my SparkSession:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("RS-LDA")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate();
```

Let me know if you'd like to see more of my code.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the default values of Spark in `log4j-defaults.properties`? This default properties file is usually located in your Spark installation path (`/etc/spark2/...`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IntelliJ and Spark and, this work for me:

```
Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```

You could change Log Spark configurations too.

```
$ cd SPARK_HOME/conf
$ gedit log4j.properties.template

# find this lines in the file
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console

and change to ERROR

log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console

In this file you have other options tho change too

# Set the default spark-shell log level to WARN. When running the spark-shell, the
# log level for this class is used to overwrite the root logger's log level, so that
# the user can have different defaults for the shell and regular Spark apps.
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=WARN

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
.....

And finally rename the log4j.properties.template file
 $ mv log4j.properties.template log4j.properties
```

You can follow this link for further configuration:

[Logging in Spark with Log4j](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-logging.html)

or this one too:

[Logging in Spark with Log4j. How to customize the driver and executors for YARN cluster mode.](https://medium.com/@cupreous.bowels/logging-in-spark-with-log4j-how-to-customize-a-driver-and-executors-for-yarn-cluster-mode-1be00b984a7c)

Answer (score 0):

It might be an old question, but I just ran by the same problem.
To fix it what I did was:

1. Adding `private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Spark.class);`
   as a field for the class.
2. `spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("WARN");` after creating the spark session

Step 2 will work only after step 1.